# -import file from 'whatFolderName//file';

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, backbone.js, reactjs

- in my actions.js file I need to import file.js
- can you tell me how the file path should be to import file.js
- import file from 'whatFolderName//file';

-providing a sample folder structure like A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H

```
-A
    -B
        -C
            -D
                -E
                    file.js

    -F
        -G
            actions.js

    -H
```

Answer (score 0):

If it needs to be relative to the current directory actions.js is located in.

`import ../B/C/D/E/file.js`

or if it can be absolute:

`import /A/B/C/D/E/file.js`

(I was about to gouge out my eyes with a fork while trying to understand your example, but I finally got it.)

Comment: thanks for your reply...can you tell me what is the use of ../ symbol in import statements for relative path